# Tail an Azure CloudAppendBlob

Tags: c#, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'd like to get the last N blocks from a `CloudAppendBlob`. `Properties.AppendBlobCommittedBlockCount` will tell me where to start but I don't see a way to download individual blocks from a `CloudAppendBlob` using the C# api. I could download a range of bytes but then I might split append statement in the middle (ugly if this is a log).

Comment: To better illustrate what you are doing, could you provide a sample of the code you are working with where you are having a problem?

Answer (score 0):

> I could download a range of bytes but then I might split append statement in the middle (ugly if this is a log).

If I understand your scenario correctly, you are trying to retrieve some individual blocks or download a range of bytes, in order to modify/update the appended content.

As this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/understanding-block-blobs--append-blobs--and-page-blobs) states about Append Blobs:

> An append blob is comprised of blocks and is optimized for append operations. **When you modify an append blob, blocks are added to the end of the blob only**, via the [Append Block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/append-block) operation. **Updating or deleting of existing blocks is not supported**. Unlike a block blob, **an append blob does not expose its block IDs**.

As I known, we could also leverage [Azure Table Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables) to store logs. Or you could clarify your detailed requirement via this operation, then we could provide you with some better solutions to achieve it.